# Когда лучше использовать TextChoices, а когда таблицу в БД Django?

Tags: django, django-model

Вопрос состоит вот в чем, когда лучше будет использовать отдельную таблицу в БД для хранения данных, а когда можно просто прибегнуть к созданию класса, который будет наследоваться от TextChoices и выбирать данные оттуда?
Правильно ли я понимаю, что отдельную таблицу нужно создавать только в том случае, если количество полей выбора будет периодически добавляться? Что-то вроде жанров к фильмам, по мере добавления новых фильмов могут и появляться новые жанры, следовательно лучше использовать таблицу. А те данные что будут константными, например, вышел ли сериал, идет он или только анонсирован, можно использовать просто класс?